# How to make columns in a choicebox

Tags: java, javafx

I want to display in my choice box 2 strings with information from an array but want them like this:

```
john            blue 
walter          red
anotherguy      purple
```

I have tried string formatting but this didn't help.

Did I do something wrong or is there some other way to do it or not?

```
public class DaagIemandUit extends GridPane {

private DomeinController dc;
private List<String[]> lijstvanspelers;
private int moeilijkheidsgraad;

public DaagIemandUit(DomeinController dc) {
    this.dc = dc;
    moeilijkheidsgraad = dc.geefMoeilijkheidsgraad();

    buildGui();

}

public void buildGui() {
    lijstvanspelers = dc.geefLijstMetSpelers(moeilijkheidsgraad);


    ChoiceBox beschikbareSpelers = new ChoiceBox();
    Button maakUitdagingAan = new Button("daag uit!");

    setVgap(10);
    setHgap(10);
    setPadding(new Insets(25));



    for (int i = 0; i < lijstvanspelers.size(); i++) {
        String[] get = lijstvanspelers.get(i);

        String text = String.format("%-25s %-10s", get[0], get[1]);
        beschikbareSpelers.getItems().add(text);
    }

    add(naamUitdaging, 0, 0);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `String.format` you have specified the minimum length, but not the maximum length of a string.

Use `String text = String.format("%-25.25s %-10.10s", get[0], get[1]);` to have the strings truncated at their respective lengths, left aligned and whitespace padded.